# Well definedness of multiplicity of a polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be a field. Let $a \in F$ be a root of $f(x)$. The multiplicity of $a$ is the maximum positive integer $m$ such that $(x-a)^m |f(x)$.

I know that $x-a$ is an irreducible. How does this imply that the multiplicity of $a$ is well defined?

I know an argument where I can prove that the map $f(x)\mapsto (x-a) f(x)$ is injective. But I'd like to know the answer to the question above.

Comment: I don't understand. The multiplicity is well defined because that definition is unambiguous. Given $a$ and $f$ you can calculate the multiplicity.

Comment: All you need to know for that definition to be well-defined is that the set of $m$ such that $(x - a)^m | f(x)$ is bounded above, and this follows by degree considerations, since it's at most $\deg f$. You don't kneed to know anything about irreducibility, and you don't even need to know that polynomials have unique factorizations, although without those this definition would be a lot less useful.

Comment: Now, there's a *different* definition you could use, which is "the exponent of $x - a$ in the irreducible factorization of $f(x)$," and for *that* definition to make sense you'd need to know that polynomials have unique factorization and that $x - a$ is irreducible. This is arguably a better definition because it gives you more of a sense of why you would care about multiplicity.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, that is the definition I wanted to work with. Perhaps, I could've been clearer in the question. All useful answers and comments. I figured out the answer. For the sake of completion, I'm accepting the answer below as conclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially this boils down to proving that $\{m \in \mathbb{N} : (X- a)^m | f\}$ is bounded. If so, then its maximum is well defined. Suppose not: then, for each natural $m$ we have that $(X- a)^m | f$ and so there exists a polynomial $g_m$ such that

$$
g_m(X- a)^m = f.
$$

**If $f$ is non zero**, then $g_m$ can't be zero for any $m$ and thus taking degrees we get that

$$
\deg f = \deg g_m + m \geq m \quad (\forall m \in \mathbb{N})
$$

which is absurd since $\deg f$ is a finite value.